# How to send encoded file from Delphi to Android via socket

Tags: java, android, delphi, sockets, serversocket

I'm trying send encoded file from delphi to android via socket
I'm using delphi xe4

here is my delphi code

```
procedure sendData();
begin
  dbdata = encodeFile('D:\data.sql');
  Memo1.Text := dbdata;
  ssMobile.Socket.Connections[cmbDevice.ItemIndex].SendText(dbdata + #10#13);
end;
```

and here is my android code

```
private void receiveFile() {
    try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
        String read = input.readLine();
        if (!read.isEmpty()) {
            if (read.contains("enddb")){
                isFile = false;
            }
            byte[] dbAsBytes = read.getBytes();
            File filePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/data.sql");
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filePath, true);
            os.write(dbAsBytes);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

here is my memo1.text

```
U1FMaXRlIGZvcm1hdCAzABAAAQEAQCAgAAAAPAAAAAkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAkA
AAABAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA8AC3iJw0PowAHBn8AD6cL+Q9u
C5cG1QtuBn8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...
```

here is my received file

```
U1FMaXRlIGZvcm1hdCAzABAAAQEAQCAgAAAAPAAAAAkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAkA
U1FMaXRlIGZvcm1hdCAzABAAAQEAQCAgAAAAPAAAAA
U1FMaXRlIGZvcm1hdCAzABAAAQEAQCAgAAAAPAAA
U1FMaXRlIGZvcm1hdCAzABAAAQEAQCAgAAAAPA
U1FMaXRlIGZvcm1hdCAzABAAAQEAQCAgAAAA
U1FMaXRlIGZvcm1hdCAzABAAAQEAQCAgAA
U1FMaXRlIGZvcm1hdCAzABAAAQEAQCAg
```

What's wrong with my code??
my received file is not same with my sent data??

Comment: What is the problem and what is your expected output? You are saying that something is wrong with your code but it is not obvious why you think it's wrong.

Comment: @kkuilla my received file is not same with my data sent

Comment: Did you check what is transmitted on the wire? Maybe it is a bug in you server socket component. I recommend to use Internet Direct (Indy) or Synapse.

Comment: Minor problem: why is the data followed by two line terminators? For readLine, both `\n` and  `\r` terminate the line.